# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined

Tags: jquery, joomla, undefined, typeerror

this problem appears only in joomla -

im trying to use the contentflow plugin with my joomla site

this is the plugin site - http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

this is my site - http://2-dweb.com/RND/

as you can see it doesnt work - it just stays on the loading phase forever

upon closer inspection i can see that there is a problem with this code:

```
  if (this.content.nodeName == "IMG") {
    CFobj._imagesToLoad++;

    var foobar = function () { 
        CFobj._imagesToLoad--;
        this.image = this.content;
        this.setImageFormat(this.image);
        if ( CFobj.conf.reflectionHeight > 0) {
            this.addReflection();
        }
        this.initClick();
        CFobj._addItemCueProcess(true);
    }.bind(this);

    if (this.content.complete && this.content.width > 0)
        window.setTimeout(foobar, 100);
    else if (this.Browser.IE && !this.content.onload) {
        var self = this;
        var t = window.setInterval( function () {
            if (self.content.complete && self.content.width > 0) {
                window.clearInterval(t);
                foobar();
            }
        }, 10);
    }
    else
        this.content.onload = window.setTimeout(foobar, 100);
}
else {
    this.initClick();
    CFobj._addItemCueProcess(true);
}

};
```

with the first line - it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined "

but this thing works on my desktop html file and on the plugin site it self!

why doesnt it work on my joomla site?
its not a conflict thing - im using no-conflict and i have other jquery plugins that work

update:

rob w helped me with this error:
"Change the first line to if (this.content && this.content.nodeName == "IMG") {. That solves the problem"

and it did, but now another error appears:

```
  initClick: function () {
        var cItem = this.clickItem;
        this[this._activeElement].addEvent('click', cItem, false);
    },
```

the error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEvent' of undefined

Comment: Change the first line to `if (this.content && this.content.nodeName == "IMG") {`. That solves the problem.

Comment: ok it fixed one problem, but now on this code theres a problem:

initClick: function () {
        var cItem = this.clickItem;
        this[this._activeElement].addEvent('click', cItem, false);
    }

it says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEvent' of undefined"

Comment: Found an identical problem when trying to use with Rails (3.2.15) - applies even when using via the `contentflow` gem.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something similar where the error occurs? Is it somehow reproducable?

Comment: Not really, it's not the code itself I suspect so much as its interaction with the framework (or maybe some obscure jQuery deprecation between versions).

Answer (score 22):

As the error explains "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined " The element is not available when the script tries to access it. You can solve this in two ways.

- Try to wrap to code with a document.ready.
- You can check whether the element is available before accessing it. To get this done use a if clause.

Comment: I think the JS in the file may have already been wrapped in `document.ready`, but I will definitely check.

Comment: It looks like that's not it. I thought it might be to do with the bindings but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

Solved this.

I am using bootstrap.css version 3.3.7 and bootstrap.js version 4.0.0.

By changing bootstrap.js to version 3.3.7 my issue got resolved!!!

Answer (score 1):

Load your script only **after loading all the elements into DOM**.

Your script should be called at the bottom of the page like this

```
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <!--HTML Elements here-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you are **using jquery**, you can include the script file anywhere in your page if it is wrapped in `document.ready`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // your code here.. 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important that you use `class="content"`. The structure should be:

```
 <div class="ContentFlow" id="cover-menu">
        <div class="flow">
            <div class="item" >
                <div class="content">
                   //your stuff
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

was with this error. I made the correction leaving all the js and css of the bootstrap with the same version.
In my case I used the latest version of each:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed  with colspan.

```
<tfoot>
   <tr class="fw-bolder fs-6">
       <th colspan="6" class="text-nowrap align-end">Total:</th>
       <th colspan="3"  class="text-danger fs-3"></th>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```

total columns 9, good luck.