# react unknown error "index.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Using React and Bootstrap to create a dialog (deleted everything unnecessary, but the error persists):

```
import React, {
    Component,
} from 'react';

import {
    Modal,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
    

class MyDialog_MultiSelect extends Component<any, any> {

    constructor(
        props:      any
    ) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                animation       = {false}
                aria-labelledby = "contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                backdrop        = "static"
                centered
                dialogClassName =  "ms-modal"
                keyboard        = {true}
                show            = {true}
                size            = "lg"
            >
                <Modal.Header 
                    closeButton
                >
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDialog_MultiSelect;
```

When opening a dialog in the browser console (Chrome), an error is displayed:

```
index.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null
    at _e (index.js:63)
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (index.js:63)
```

The dialog works, but this error is annoying.

What is this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Maybe you need to check your bootstrap css/js [versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51132977/2873538).

Comment: @Ajeet Shah, bootstrap.js  v4.5.2, bootsrtap.css v4.5.2, bootstrap-css-only v4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of the Google Chrome extensions, I'm not sure which one, I just uninstalled them all, but I hope it works for you!
Found the answer here: https://itchief.ru/bootstrap/modal